# Is it possible to get/set values from a pointer vector<json>?

Tags: c++, json, vector, nlohmann-json

I am currently experimenting with C++, basically I am trying to find the most repeated values in a very huge array using vectors and json. However to make my code more efficient I've decided to use threading, however my knowledge of pointers and addresses doesn't seem to work on this one.

Basically I am trying to do this :

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "json.hpp"

void read(vector<json> * repeatitions, bool *done){
    // ... more code from here
    cout << "from thread:" << repeatitions->size() << endl; // this works
    cout << *repeatitions[0 % data_multiplier]["0"].is_null() << endl; // this doesn't

    *done = true; // - works obviously
}

int main(){
   // ... more code from here
   bool done = false;
   vector<json> repeatitions(10);
   thread worker(read, &repeatitions, &done);
   worker.join();

   return 0;
}
```

for some reason it gives me :

```
 error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'vector<json>' (aka 'vector<basic_json<>>')
    cout << repeatitions[0 % data_multiplier]["0"].is_null() << endl;

note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'std::vector<nlohmann::basic_json<>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY reference       operator[](size_type __n) _NOEXCEPT;

note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'std::vector<nlohmann::basic_json<>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY const_reference operator[](size_type __n) const _NOEXCEPT;
```

If this is not possible, I am planning to make it static however I am not very familiar with static variables I am very hesitant to do this as I want to make my code as efficiently as possible. I hope you can give some insight about this, thanks :)

**edit
reproducible error:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;
using namespace std;

void read(vector<json> *repeatitions, bool *done){
    // ... more code from here
    cout << "from thread:" << repeatitions->size() << endl; // this works
    cout << repeatitions[0]["test"].is_null() << endl; // this doesn't
    cout << repeatitions[0]["test"] << endl; // this doesn't

    *done = true; // - works obviously
}

int main(){
   // ... more code from here
   bool done = false;
   vector<json> repeatitions(1);
   repeatitions[0]["test"] = "test";
   thread worker(read, &repeatitions, &done);
   worker.join();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems like it would be easier and more sensible to use a reference instead of a pointer. Ex. `vector<json> & repeatitions`.

Comment: *I am currently experimenting with C++* -- C++ is one of the most complex computer languages out there.  You cannot learn it properly by cherry-picking topics -- it can only be learned from following peer-reviewed books and tutorials.  Just the fact you are not aware of pointers, `static`, etc., but want to jump right into multithreaded programming is a sign that things will not go too well.

Comment: I am currently trying to fuzz and learn not anything too serious so don't worry :)

Comment: I'm guessing this `*repeatitions[0 % data_multiplier]["0"].is_null()` should be this `(*repeatitions)[0 % data_multiplier]["0"].is_null()`. Or better still use a reference, instead of a pointer.

Comment: Note to the other commenters here: You cannot pass a plain reference to `std::thread`. The object will be copied if this is attempted.

Comment: @Mestkon That's what you use a `std::reference_wrapper` for. `thread worker(read, std::ref(repeatitions), std::ref(done));` - then take them by a normal reference in the function

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know, I specifically stated *plain* reference for that reason

Comment: @ted-lyngmo I do not know how it compiles for you, for me it doesn't. But I've put it on the edit section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not using the name `read` (it may conflict with other `read`s - especially since you do `using namespace std;` in the global scope - so don't do that).

Also, pass by reference to the thread function. It's easier to deal with. You do that by packaging them in `std::reference_wrapper`s (using `std::ref`).

Example:

```cpp
#include "json.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using json = nlohmann::json;

void mread(std::vector<json>& repeatitions, bool& done) {
    using namespace std;
    // ... more code from here
    cout << "from thread:" << repeatitions.size() << endl; // this works
    cout << repeatitions[0]["test"].is_null() << endl;     // this now works
    cout << repeatitions[0]["test"] << endl;               // this now works

    done = true;
}

int main() {
    // ... more code from here
    bool done = false;
    std::vector<json> repeatitions(1);
    repeatitions[0]["test"] = "test";
    std::thread worker(mread, std::ref(repeatitions), std::ref(done));
    worker.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
from thread:1
0
"test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a pointer causes you to get the address of something, it can either be used to access the value that resides inside that address, or to allocate an array, which if you are not using C is not recommended. Vector itself already acts like an array. So when you say `std::vector<your_type>*` you should be aiming to create either an array of arrays, or to reference a vector. In this case, you are trying to reference it. So learn and use references `&`.

Using `*repeatitions[0 % data_multiplier]["0"]` means that you are trying to access the '0 % data_multiplier'th element of a vector array, and in that element you try to get "0" indexed element (which must be a pointer to an object that has a method called `is_null()` ) and you are de-referencing it to get the value that the pointer is pointing to.

Also, since you are learning, instead of doing `(*object).method()` you can just do `object->method()` when de-referencing.

Comment: Using a reference in `std::thread` will copy the data. It might not be what we want